# ORA-01747 error invalid user.table.column, table.column, or columns specification

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, proc, reserved-words

i wrote this proc in sqldevelopers and i **think** i got this error since the fields :"no" and "year" are reserved words i tried to fix it using brackets but it doesnt seems to help...
hope you will be able to help..
thanks!!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SALES_BY_CLIENT (
p_p_ITEM_CODE varchar2,
p_p_DATE_from date,
p_p_DATE_TO date, 
p_p_CLIENT_CODE varchar2, cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as
begin
 open cur for select * from 
 SL_DOC_LINES SDL
join SL_DOCUMENTS SD
on SDL.DOC_NO=SD.[NO] and SDL.DOC_YEAR=sd.[YEAR] and SDL.DOC_COUNTER_CODE=SD.COUNTER_CODE and SDL.DOC_BRANCH_CODE=SD.BRANCH_CODE
 where SDL.IT_CODE=p_p_ITEM_CODE AND (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SD.DOC_DATE)>EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p_p_DATE_from) and EXTRACT(DAY FROM SD.DOC_DATE)<= EXTRACT(DAY FROM p_p_DATE_TO)) and SD.CLI_CODE=p_p_CLIENT_CODE;
 end;
/
```

Comment: Could you show your table definitions with column names? Definitely don't use the brackets, that is not valid syntax. `NO` and `YEAR` can be used as column names, they aren't reserved words. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621

Comment: my tables are extremely long so i  will just show the column definitions SL_DOC_LINES:"DOC_YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
 "DOC_BRANCH_CODE" NUMBER(6,0), 
 "DOC_COUNTER_CODE" NUMBER(6,0), 
 "DOC_NO" NUMBER(9,0),       and the SL_documents: "DOC_BRANCH_CODE" NUMBER(6,0), 
 "YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
 "NO" NUMBER(9,0), "COUNTER_CODE" NUMBER(6,0),  i hope you got somthing with all the mess... anyway thanks!!

Comment: Are those the only columns in those tables? Because you're doing `select *`, so the cursor is trying to include every column in both of those tables.

Comment: While column names like NO and YEAR may be acceptable to Oracle, they are very poor choices for humans.  Give some thought to your naming conventions, and try to make names 'self documenting'.  What is column NO represent?  A number?  Fine. Number of what?  YEAR?  Year of what?  Consider making every column name to be, at a minimum, two words - adjective_noun.  And think about confusion and consistency.  Not "NO", but "EMPLOYEE_NBR".  Not "YEAR" but "SALES_YEAR".

Comment: If you're using Oracle, you can't use brackets like you can in SQL Server. Those need to be removed.

Comment: Oracle uses double-quotes (") to quote names. SQL Server uses square braces ([]). Which database are you actually using?

Comment: im using Oracle and i cant change the names of DB since im working for a client wich use this DB and it will  cause errors....